# Runtime Error(NZEC) in codechef for python3

Tags: python

I'm getting error for this code :

```
#Finding largest number

elements = []
nl = input("Enter number of lines :")
for i in range(0,int(nl)):
    print("Enter number of elements in line", i+1, ": ")
    ne = input()
    elements = [None]*int(ne)
    print("Enter elements :")
    maximum = 0
    for j in range(0,int(ne)):
        elements[j] = input()
    for j in range(0,int(ne)):
        if int(elements[j]) > maximum:
        maximum = int(elements[j])
print("Maximum number in line", i+1, "is", maximum,"\n\n")
```

I submitted this code on codechef it showed me Runtime Error(NZEC) error

please help!

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: its correct . i have tested the code in my pc.

Comment: Try copying it from your question and running it again...

Comment: i edited it on my question. Check it now and let me know>

Comment: While copying the code from pc to the question space it got messed up. Sorry for that! But now its correct

Comment: Okay. You want to find the max. Just use `max()`? Also, Are integers input on a line separated by spaces or separate lines?

Comment: using max() will fix the issue? integers are separated by lines.

Comment: Modify my answer as needed. Also, typecast as you receive it. Do not typecast dynamically, that is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your numbers are input on a single line, separated by spaces. You'll need to make a couple of changes.

```
for i in range(0, int(input())):
    elements = []
    maximum = -float('inf')
    ne = int(input())
    elements = list(map(int, input().split())) # assuming space separated integers

    for e in elements:
        if e > maximum:
        maximum = e

print("Maximum number in line", i+1, "is", maximum, "\n\n")
```

---

Alternatively you can substitute the max-finding loop with

```
maximum = max(elements)
```

---

If your numbers are newline separated, create an empty list and append to it in a loop.

```
...
ne = int(input())

elements = []
for j in range(0, ne):
    elements.append(int(input()))

...
```

Comment: okay . I'm just a beginner so i dont know much about python functions yet. Thanks for your help bro!

Comment: @COLDSPEED sorry I'm new to this community. Need little more time to get to know how things work! sorry for this time! :\

Comment: @TanmayMane No worries. You can also up vote answers if you have > 15 rep :) You'll get used to it.

Comment: i just did! :D
Thanks for your help!